# Automaticallyut MSTest all test methods in a solution in Command Line

Tags: mstest

The MSTest allows to run tests in specify assemblies to test through /testcontainer or metalist through /testmetadata; But is there a way to automatically run all tests in a solution, whithout specifing any name of dlls/meta files? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not what you want to hear, but the answer is no, by default you are limited to the `/testcontainer` or `/testmetadata` options for specifying which tests to run.

You could easily run MSTest multiple times for each DLL in your project which contains tests.  You could even run a process that analyzes your DLLs for tests and build up a list of DLLs which contain tests and then run a script that calls mstest for each of those DLLs.